# How to reset formula in Crystal Reports when trying to show a section on every page

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

My question is maybe not good, but here is the thing. I export my report in two types: PDF and HTML. In my designer, I am using Page Header for my grid and I need that section on every page of PDF file and only on the first page of HTML file. I made a bool parameter(which I pass through c# code) and use this formula on the "x-2" button of Suppress option of the section:

```
if MyBool = true
PageNumber > 1 // HTML case
else
"" // PDF case     I need a blank formula in else case because I will show this section on every page
```

So, the problem is else case, where I tried with "false", but it is not working. So, basically I need opposite of the "PageNumber > 1". In my code, I only passed the parameter like this:

```
mainReport.SetParameterValue("MyBool", false);
```

Thanks.

Comment: you want to supress the `page header` or you want to `PageNumber>1` when it is HTML?

Comment: @Siva Not sure you understood, I don't want to check Suppress option, I just want to find opposite of the "PageNumber > 1" and put it in else case. In the first case (HTML), I use PageNumber > 1 (without suppressing) and it shows Page Header section on the first page (which is good), but in PDF case, I only need that formula blank, or something in else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether I have addressed your problem.. but I want to suggest below approach.

Since you are writing in supress formula:

```
If (MyBool = true  and PageNumber > 1)
true // HTML and XLS case
else
false // PDF case
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is the situation:

[image]

Picture 1: What I do in the designer

[image]

Picture 2: What I want in the PDF file

[image]

Picture 3: What I want in HTML file

I hope it is clear now @Siva.

Comment: that I got and provided my approach.. but changed a bi will you try now?